# Question: Call the function and passing in an anonymous arrow function that alerts the spliced value

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Apologize upfront, I am very new to JS. Having trouble finding out where I should put the arrow function here for this question. I've tried putting it in the parameters when I call the function but that seems very wrong. Exact question is: Call the processSplicedValue function again, but this time pass in an anonymous arrow function that alerts the spliced value.

```
const heroList = [
  "Batman",
  "SuperMan",
  "Ironman",
  "War Machine",
  "Black Widow",
  "SpiderMan",
];

function processSplicedValue(array, spliceInd, functionProcess) {
  var hero = heroList.splice(spliceInd, 1);
  functionProcess(hero);
}

processSplicedValue(processSplicedValueList, 0, () => alert);
```

Comment: `processSplicedValue(heroList, 0, alert);` simply pass alert.

Comment: Yeah that's what I want to do too, but the question is asking for an arrow function. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, functions are first-class citizens i.e they can be passed around just like any other variables.

You're passing an argument as a function that takes no arguments and returns another function (here `alert`). So even if you pass some arguments when calling the callback as `functionProcess(hero)`, it does nothing.

You can however accept an argument (`x`) in the callback and then use it in your alert like so :

```js
const heroList = [
  "Batman",
  "SuperMan",
  "Ironman",
  "War Machine",
  "Black Widow",
  "SpiderMan",
];

function processSplicedValue(array, spliceInd, functionProcess) {
  var hero = heroList.splice(spliceInd, 1);
  functionProcess(hero);
  console.log("[processSplicedValue] called")
}

processSplicedValue(heroList, 0, (x) => alert(x));
```

OR

just simply pass in `alert` as callback like so since it's just another function

```js
const heroList = [
  "Batman",
  "SuperMan",
  "Ironman",
  "War Machine",
  "Black Widow",
  "SpiderMan",
];

function processSplicedValue(array, spliceInd, functionProcess) {
  var hero = heroList.splice(spliceInd, 1);
  functionProcess(hero);
  console.log("[processSplicedValue] called")
}

processSplicedValue(heroList, 0, alert);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the short explanation, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

## I think this should help

```js
processSplicedValue(processSplicedValueList, 0, message => alert(message));
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch seeing it like this does help!